# Database query not functioning as expected

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, syntax-error

Hi i'm using a query to extract data from the table, from a dynamic link. and ummm the code I've used SEEMS to be okay, yet i get a 'Database Query Failed' can someone tell me why?

here's the code:

```
<?php
$PIN = $_GET['Pin'];

$query="SELECT * FROM Accident_Investigation WHERE PIN = $PIN";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(!$result){
    die("Database query failed.");
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `die()`, use `echo mysqli_error($connection);` and read the error message that outputs (if any).

Comment: where is `$connection` defined ?

Comment: Can change, WHERE PIN = '$PIN' ?

Comment: Maybe connection isn't defined. Maybe PIN is a string and should be in quoatas?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: thanks guys, Amal Murali great suggestion :) I love StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$PIN` to `'$PIN'` in SQL statement provided everything else works fine.

Comment: Also [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) will be useful.

Comment: Sanitize the string before directing it directly from $_GET.

Comment: Yes, one can refer to this link => http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

SQL injection prevention are next steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$PIN = (!isset($_GET['Pin']) ? $_GET['Pin'] : null);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Accident_Investigation WHERE PIN = '" . $PIN . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result){
  mysqli_error($connection);
  die("Database query failed.");
}
```

Comment: If PIN is an int, it shouldn't, AFAIK be in quotes, should it?

Comment: Do NOT use empty() like this, ESPECIALLY if the valid inputs can contain `0`. `empty(0)` is true.

Comment: If it does happen to be an int, it won't matter. But if it happens to be a date, char or varchar, it sets things straight.

Comment: thanks mann, what i had to do was to add the quotes to $PIN. like so WHERE PIN = '$PIN'